# Extracting number from string in Python with regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract and print a variable number '-34.99' from the string:

```
myString = "Test1 [cm]:     -35.00/-34.99/-34.00/0.09"
```

The values in the string will change.
How can I do it with the regular expression in Python?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You always want the second number in the `/` separated list?

Comment: If the string always looks like that, regex is overkill: `myString.split()[-1].split("/")[1]`

Comment: DSM, in my code a myString is large number of rows. I use regex and re.compile to find others strings. Thanks for your useful answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Non-regex solution is:

```
myString = "Test1 [cm]:     -35.00/-34.99/-34.00/0.09"  
print myString.split("/")[1]
```

Test this code [here](http://ideone.com/mjTmG).

---

One of regex solutions would be:

```
import re 
myString = "Test1 [cm]:     -35.00/-34.99/-34.00/0.09" 
print re.search(r'(?<=\/)[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?', myString).group()
```

Test this code [here](http://ideone.com/ERe7H).

Explanation:

```
(?<=\/)[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?
└──┬──┘└─┬─┘└┬┘└───┬────┘
   │     │   │     │
   │     │   │     └ optional period with one or more trailing digits
   │     │   │
   │     │   └ one or more digits
   │     │
   │     └ optional + or -
   │
   └ leading slash before match
```

Comment: Great! It works! Thanks to all!. Omega, your answer is the best!

Comment: You might consider `.split('/')[-3]`.  Getting "third-last" Would protect from descriptions containing "/" character.

Comment: Your regex only works for fields beyond the first. ie, -35.00 is not matched since there is no leading '/'

Comment: @Jon - I believe slash is a separator, so there should be no such character in description

Comment: @Pyson - You should read question again to see what OP wants to parse/match. My answer does exactly what OP is asking for...

Comment: Chill mate. I pointed this out for the benefit of the OP (or other reading this answer) in case he wanted to change the field he was looking for to the first.

Comment: Actualy, I need to exctract only avg number. Stats format:   Test1 [cm]:                   [ min/avg/max/mdev ]

Answer (score 1):

For something like this, re.findall works great:

```
>>> import re
>>> myString = "Test1 [cm]:     -35.00/-34.99/-34.00/0.09"
>>> re.findall(r'([+-]?\d+\.\d+)',myString)
['-35.00', '-34.99', '-34.00', '0.09']
```

You can get the floats directly with a list comprehension:

```
>>> [float(f) for f in re.findall(r'([+-]?\d+\.\d+)',myString)]
[-35.0, -34.99, -34.0, 0.09]
```

Or the second one like this:

```
>>> re.findall(r'([+-]?\d+\.\d+)',myString)[1]
'-34.99'
```

The question will be how big a range of textual floating points will you accept? Some with no decimal points? Exponents?

```
>>> myString = "Test1 [cm]:     -35.00/-34.99/-34.00/0.09/5/1.0e6/1e-6"
```

Ouch! -- this is getting harder with a regex.

You actually may be better off just using Python's string ops:

```
>>> ''.join([s for s in myString.split() if '/' in s]).split('/')
['-35.00', '-34.99', '-34.00', '0.09', '5', '1.0e6', '1e-6']
```

You can get the nth one same way:

```
>>> n=2
>>> ''.join([s for s in myString.split() if '/' in s]).split('/')[n]
'-34.00'
```

Then all the weird cases work without a harder regex:

```
>>> map(float,''.join([s for s in myString.split() if '/' in s]).split('/'))
[-35.0, -34.99, -34.0, 0.09, 5.0, 1000000.0, 1e-06]
```

Comment: I was a little worried about the units, though: if "[cm]" were "[cm/s]", then the first few terms would be weird..

Comment: @DSM: yes, I guess you could validate the split pieced as having digits or use a try block. The OP only seemed concerned about the second match since the chosen regex only works for matches beyond the first field.

Comment: That's why I went with `myString.split()[-1].split("/")[1]`, although it will fail on other cases, too.  Maybe `map(float, myString[myString.find(':')+1:].split("/"))`?  With only one example to go from, it's hard to know how general to be, or what invariants we can rely on. I do like the idea of using the separator instead of writing a complicated regex to handle all the cases, though.